# XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/apache2/xdebug_remote.log' in Docker

Tags: docker, xdebug, remote-debugging, docker-container

I have a Docker container with all my PHP7 enviroment for develop and everything works well except xdebug. The extension is enabled, with all the correct settings to enable remote debug, I setted up the remote host which is ok but when I make a request to a website inside this container if I check the apache error log I see this error:

> [Thu Jun 01 05:44:31.529883 2017] [:error] [pid 916] [client 172.18.0.1:40306] XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/apache2/xdebug_remote.log'., referer: XXXXXXX

The file xdebug_remote.log has all the privileges, so this in theory would not be the problem. So, anyone has any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, did you ever find a solution?